# How do you run a single test/spec file in RSpec?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

I want to be able to run a single spec file's tests — for the one file I'm editing, for example.  `rake spec` executes all the specs.  My project is not a Rails project, so `rake spec:doc` doesn't work.

Don't know if this matters, but here is my directory structure.

```
./Rakefile
./lib
./lib/cushion.rb
./lib/cushion
./lib/cushion/doc.rb
./lib/cushion/db.rb
./spec
./spec/spec.opts
./spec/spec_helper.rb
./spec/db_spec.rb
```

Answer (score 441, accepted):

Or you can skip rake and use the 'rspec' command:

```
bundle exec rspec path/to/spec/file.rb
```

In your case I think as long as your ./spec/db_spec.rb file includes the appropriate helpers, it should work fine.

If you're using an older version of rspec it is:

```
bundle exec spec path/to/spec/file.rb
```

Comment: with the new rspec you have to use "rspec path/to/file.rb"

Comment: Maybe I'm doing it wrong, but I have to do "bundle exec rspec path/to/spec/file.rb"

Comment: If you're using Rails you'll probably want to execute your specs using Rake in order to ensure you are starting from a blank database.

Comment: @andrhamm, you're just running your specs in the context of your bundle. This is necessary if you're not using gemsets (which come by default with rvm, and are a separate extension to rbenv)

Comment: If you want to run only one test you append the line number of the start of the test to the file. Example: rspec path/to/spec/file.rb:455

Comment: add `f` before the `it` so `fit "expects something ...` will only run the specific test

Answer (score 213):

The raw invocation:

```
rake spec SPEC=spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb \
          SPEC_OPTS="-e \"should log in with cookie\""
```

Now figure out how to embed this into your editor.

Comment: As I said, I'm not in rails so there's no controllers.  But yes, "rake spec SPEC=file.rb" works.  Thanks!  I'm working on the Emacs integration now.

Comment: Don't launch the rakefile if you can avoid it. It takes frickin ages

Comment: Just run the spec file directly!  See Orion Edwards's answer.

Comment: I changed the accepted answer, but the SPEC_OPTS param was helpful to me also.

Comment: Now that's what I call a good answer. Why isn't it marked as "Answer"?

Comment: Running spec directly is _often_ the best choice, but there are many times when you have to run rake for various magic bits in a custom Rakefile

Comment: When running Rspec in Rails, I've found `SPEC_OPTS` doesn't work. I have to specify the line number using `SPEC=<file>:<line>` kind of like in @juanpaco's answer.

Answer (score 138):

This question is an old one, but it shows up at the top of Google when searching for how to run a single test.  I don't know if it's a recent addition, but to run a single test out of a spec you can do the following:

```
rspec path/to/spec:<line number>
```

where -line number- is a line number that contains part of your test.  For example, if you had a spec like:

```
1: 
2: it "should be awesome" do
3:   foo = 3
4:   foo.should eq(3)
5: end
6:
```

Let's say it's saved in spec/models/foo_spec.rb.  Then you would run:

```
rspec spec/models/foo_spec.rb:2
```

and it would just run that one spec.  In fact, that number could be anything from 2 to 5.

Comment: This is interesting, although it looks like it doesn't work once you refactor your spec into multiple files (i.e. you can only use it with the main _spec.rb file, but if none of your examples are in it, it will run nothing. Also if you try to use it for a file which isn't a top-level spec file, that will also run nothing.)

Comment: I don't quite follow.  What do you mean by "top-level spec file?"  My test suite is pretty much always divided across several files, and I can always invoke tests in a single file using this method.  Do you mean having a file that `require`s your other spec files?

Comment: I can use this on any file at any level under the spec/ directory.  I believe Trejkaz is incorrect.

Comment: This colon-notation did not work for me.  I got: a `No such file or directory` error.

Comment: Huh.  Can you post exactly what your command-line invocation was?

Comment: I use this all the time, but sometimes you want to run several tests from one file. Then you can type all examples like this: `rspec spec/models/foo_spec.rb:2:12:49`

Answer (score 67):

You can also use the actual text of the *e*xample test case with `-e` !

So for:

```
it "shows the plane arrival time"
```

you can use

```
rspec path/to/spec/file.rb -e 'shows the plane arrival time'
./scripts/spec path/to/spec/file.rb -e 'shows the plane arrival time'
```

no need for rake here.

Comment: This is all you need, except that "spec" should be replaced by "rspec" as stated @bandhunt

Answer (score 19):

from help (spec -h):

```
-l, --line LINE_NUMBER           Execute example group or example at given line.
                                 (does not work for dynamically generated examples)
```

Example:  spec spec/runner_spec.rb -l 162

Comment: In newer Rspec versions you append the line number after a colon `:` per the documentation and a popular answer.

Answer (score 17):

To run **all** of your rspec files: `rspec`

*note: you must be in the root of your project*

To run **one** rspec file: `rspec 'path_to/spec.rb'`

*note: replace 'path_to/spec.rb' with your path. Quotation marks optional.*

To run **one** rspec **test** from one file: `rspec 'path_to/spec.rb:7'`

*note: :7 is the line number where the test starts*

Answer (score 13):

If you installed rspec as a plugin rather than as a gem, then you won't have the `spec` executable.

At any rate, All you need to do is run the file using ruby. The rspec code is clever enough to run the tests for you.

eg:

```
ruby myclass_spec.rb
```

Comment: Is it possible to run one test within the file like this?

Answer (score 12):

http://github.com/grosser/single_test lets you do stuff like..

```
rake spec:user          #run spec/model/user_spec.rb (searches for user*_spec.rb)
rake test:users_c       #run test/functional/users_controller_test.rb
rake spec:user:token    #run the first spec in user_spec.rb that matches /token/
rake test:user:token    #run all tests in user_test.rb that match /token/
rake test:last
rake spec:last
```

Comment: It appears that the gem hasn't been maintained, last commit was 5 years ago!

Answer (score 10):

Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3 have an easy way to run one spec file:

```
  ruby -I spec spec/models/user_spec.rb
```

Explanation:

- `ruby` command tends to be faster than the `rake` command

  `-I spec` means "include the 'spec' directory when looking for files"

  `spec/models/user_spec.rb` is the file we want to run.

Comment: Can you run one test within that file with some extra options?

Answer (score 6):

Although many great answers were written to this question, none of them uses the [Rspec `tags`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-4/docs/command-line/tag-option) approach.

I use tags to run one or more specs in different files -- only those related to my current development task.

For example, I add the tag "dev" with the value "current":

```
it "creates an user", dev: :current do
  user = create(:user)
  expect(user.persisted?).to be_truthy
end
```

then I run

```
bundle exec rspec . --tag dev:current
```

Different tags/values can be set in individual specs or groups.

Answer (score 5):

I was having trouble getting any of these examples to work, maybe because the post is old and the commands have changed?

After some poking around I found this works:

rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb

That will run just the single file and provides useful output in the terminal.

Comment: This was mentioned in a comment in the accepted answer. Yes, I think this post is just so old that the command name has changed.

Answer (score 4):

specky.vim

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, have a look at autotest.

Running autotest in a command window will mean that the spec file will be executed whenever you save it. Also, it will be run whenever the file you are speccing is run.

For instance, if you have a model spec file called person_spec.rb, and a model file that it is speccing called person.rb, then whenever you save either of these files from your editor, the spec file will be executed.

Answer (score 3):

Lets say, you're running test for creating todo. You can always run  that specific todo spec code using the file crete_spec.rb file as below.

```
      rspec/spec/features/controller/spec_file_name.rb

   Example:

   Creating  rspec spec/features/todos/create_spec.rb
   Editing   rspec spec/features/todos/edit_spec.rb
   Deleting  rspec spec/features/todos/destroy_spec.rb
```

If you want to run all the specs in one single short.

```
   rspec
```

If you want to run all the specs in a specific controller user this.

```
  rspec/spec/feaures/controller_name

  Example:   rspec/spec/features/todos
```

Hope it gives you more understanding!

Answer (score 0):

And you can run specific line into your test file

```
rspec spec/models/model_spec.rb:47
```

Comment: This same answer was provided almost 10 years ago.