# How to run a single RSpec test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have the following file:

```
/spec/controllers/groups_controller_spec.rb
```

What command in terminal do I use to run just that spec and in what directory do I run the command?

My gem file:

```
# Test ENVIRONMENT GEMS
group :development, :test do
    gem "autotest"
    gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.4"
    gem "cucumber-rails", ">=0.3.2"
    gem "webrat", ">=0.7.2"
    gem 'factory_girl_rails'
    gem 'email_spec'
end
```

**Spec file:**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe GroupsController do
  include Devise::TestHelpers

  describe "GET yourgroups" do
    it "should be successful and return 3 items" do

      Rails.logger.info 'HAIL MARRY'

      get :yourgroups, :format => :json
      response.should be_success
      body = JSON.parse(response.body)
      body.should have(3).items # @user1 has 3 permissions to 3 groups
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You can run your tests like bundle exec rspec ./spec/controllers/groups_controller_spec.rb:6, it runs this specific test only. More info here: https://kolosek.com/rails-rspec-setup

Comment: ``bundle exec rspec spec --help`` wil give you the answer:

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Not sure how long this has bee available but there is an Rspec configuration for run filtering - so now you can add this to your `spec_helper.rb`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.filter_run_when_matching :focus
end
```

And then add a focus tag to the `it`, `context` or `describe` to run only that block:

```
it 'runs a test', :focus do
  ...test code
end
```

RSpec documentation:

https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration#filter_run_when_matching-instance_method

Comment: This requires changing infrastructure. And remembering to change it back.  I would recommend not doing this and using just the `rspec` commands to run the spec with appropriate parameter to indicate which

Answer (score 584):

Usually I do:

```
rspec ./spec/controllers/groups_controller_spec.rb:42
```

Where `42` represents the line of the test I want to run.

You can also use tags. See [here](http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-3/dir/command-line/tag-option).

Using `bundle exec`:

```
bundle exec rspec ./spec/controllers/groups_controller_spec.rb:42
```

Comment: Thanks tried that it does not work when I do rake spec /spec/path...:XX I get the error /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby -S bundle exec rspec ./spec/controllers/groups_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/incoming_mails_controller_spec.rb ./spec/lib/mailing_job/mailingjob_find_reply_spec.rb ./spec/models/group_model_spec.rb ./spec/models/user_model_spec.rb

Comment: If I try using just RSPEC, i get this error: "$ rspec spec/controllers/groups_controller_spec.rb:19
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:27:in `setup': You have already activated rspec-core 2.6.2, but your Gemfile requires rspec-core 2.6.0. Consider using bundle exec. (Gem::LoadError)
"

Comment: You can try "bundle exec rspec spec/controllers/groups_controller_spec.rb:19" in that case

Comment: bundle exec worked but why? Is that a hack any way to avoid that?

Comment: it's not a hack, it makes sure you use the very same version you declared in your gemfile. In your case, the mere `rspec` failed because the version on your system is more recent than the one in your gemfile.

Comment: IMO this solution is dangerous, because it can lead you to think that a test is passing when it actually isn't - for example, if you add a few lines of code ahead of the test you're trying to fix. Tags are a better way to go.

Comment: @therin tags belong to my answer + if you assume you do things wrong, conclusion will always be wrong

Comment: Is there a way to do this using Django's test framework?

Comment: Instead of `bundle exec`, you can use [binstubs](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/wiki/Understanding-binstubs)

Comment: If you are testing shared examples from an external file, this method will attempt to run a test at the specified line in the external file as well as the original referenced file.

Comment: I had to add a . (period) to the front of the path to get it to run ---------------------linebreak---------------------
`bundle exec rspec ./spec/controllers/groups_controller_spec.rb:42`

Comment: There are a few reasons this is a bad answer and should not be the accepted answer— while it is often the quickest solution, you are bypassing the rake task and just instructing rspec to run the single test. In the past (prior to Rails 5), this worked fine. Running the rake task is better and less confusing for the dev long-term, the best is with `rake spec SPEC=`

Comment: check this `bundle exec rspec -f d spec/controllers/groups_controller_spec.rb`

Answer (score 78):

With Rake:

```
rake spec SPEC=path/to/spec.rb
```

(Credit goes to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/143934/650475).  Go vote him up.)

**EDIT** (thanks to @cirosantilli): To run one specific scenario within the spec, you have to supply a regex pattern match that matches the description.

```
rake spec SPEC=path/to/spec.rb \
          SPEC_OPTS="-e \"should be successful and return 3 items\""
```

Comment: This is the superior answer because it uses the 'rake spec' command not the 'rspec' command. That means the test database is properly re-initialized each time (which doesnt happen if you use 'rspec...')

Comment: You can use `SPEC=path/to/spec.rb:42` to run the test on the given line number, although it seems any `it_behaves_like` tests will also get run (bug?).

Answer (score 76):

You can pass a regex to the spec command which will only run `it` blocks matching the name you supply.

```
spec path/to/my_spec.rb -e "should be the correct answer"
```

**2019 Update: Rspec2 switched from the 'spec' command to the 'rspec' command.**

Comment: Thanks I tried that but it errors with: $ rake spec spec/controllers/incoming_mails_controller_spec.rb -e "should be successful and return 3 items"
rake aborted!
(eval):1:in `standard_rake_options': compile error
(eval):1: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting $end
should be successful and return 3 items

Comment: Updated with the actual spec file ideas?

Comment: If you have a compile error, your spec is not valid ruby. Make sure you are not missing a `do` after an `it`, `context` or `describe` declaration.

Comment: It's "spec", not "rake spec".

Comment: this should be the correct answer, relating to a line number is seriously wrong - any any case

Comment: That is amazing! But I think he wanted to run the test not only an example from the test (is a simple test example with only 1 example)

Comment: This should be the correct answer, line number changes way too much to be useful.

Answer (score 37):

There are many options:

```
rspec spec                           # All specs
rspec spec/models                    # All specs in the models directory
rspec spec/models/a_model_spec.rb    # All specs in the some_model model spec
rspec spec/models/a_model_spec.rb:nn # Run the spec that includes line 'nn'
rspec -e"text from a test"           # Runs specs that match the text
rspec spec --tag focus               # Runs specs that have :focus => true
rspec spec --tag focus:special       # Run specs that have :focus => special
rspec spec --tag focus ~skip         # Run tests except those with :focus => true
```

Answer (score 26):

My preferred method for running specific tests is slightly different -
I added the lines

```
  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.filter_run :focus => true
    config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true
  end
```

To my spec_helper file.

Now, whenever I want to run one specific test (or context, or spec), I can simply add the tag "focus" to it, and run my test as normal - only the focused test(s) will run. If I remove all the focus tags, the `run_all_when_everything_filtered` kicks in and runs all the tests as normal.

It's not quite as quick and easy as the command line options - it does require you to edit the file for the test you want to run. But it gives you a lot more control, I feel.

Comment: I definitely prefer this style, because I'm commonly running tests via Rubymine/intelliJ. I like this method also because its similar to using fit/xit in jasmine / with gulp

Answer (score 11):

Run the commands from your project's root directory:

```
# run all specs in the project's spec folder
bundle exec rspec 

# run specs nested under a directory, like controllers
bundle exec rspec spec/controllers

# run a single test file
bundle exec rspec spec/controllers/groups_controller_spec.rb

# run a test or subset of tests within a file
# e.g., if the 'it', 'describe', or 'context' block you wish to test
# starts at line 45, run:
bundle exec rspec spec/controllers/groups_controller_spec.rb:45
```

Additionally, you can use the `--example` (`-e`) option to run specific tests that partially or fully match text labels in your 'it', 'describe', or 'context' blocks for the given test path:

```
# run groups controller specs in blocks with a label containing 'spaghetti flag is false'
bundle exec rspec spec/controllers/groups_controller_spec.rb -e 'spaghetti flag is false'

# Less granularly, you can run specs for blocks containing a substring of text 
# that matches one or more block labels, like 'spaghetti' or 'paghett'
bundle exec rspec spec/controllers/groups_controller_spec.rb -e spaghetti
```

This will run all the tests nested inside the blocks with labels matching the string argument received by the example option.

When using the example option, I recommend also appending `--format documentation` (shorthand: `-f documentation`) to your bundle command (e.g., `bundle exec rspec spec/some_file.rb -e spaghetti -f documentation`). Documentation-formatting replaces the normal `.`/`F` output with an easy-to-read pretty printed breakdown showing the nested block labels for the examples you're running and outputs the printed label for each example (`it` block) in green or red to denote whether it passed or failed. This provides better confirmation that your example argument matches the specs you *intended* to run, and it gives live visibility to which examples are passing/failing during longer test runs where the example argument matches many block labels and/or matched blocks contain many nested examples.

**Additional Reading (Documentation Links)**

- [Example Option](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-10/docs/command-line/example-option)
- [Format Option](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-10/docs/command-line/format-option)

Answer (score 10):

@apneadiving answer is a neat way of solving this. However, now we have a new method in Rspec 3.3. We can simply run `rspec spec/unit/baseball_spec.rb[#context:#it]` instead of using a line number. Taken from [here:](http://rspec.info/blog/2015/06/rspec-3-3-has-been-released/)

> RSpec 3.3 introduces a new way to identify examples[...]
>
> For example, this command:
>
> `$ rspec spec/unit/baseball_spec.rb[1:2,1:4]`
> …would run the 2nd and 4th example or group defined under the 1st top-level group defined in spec/unit/baseball_spec.rb.

So instead of doing
`rspec spec/unit/baseball_spec.rb:42` where it (test in line 42) is the first test, we can simply do
`rspec spec/unit/baseball_spec.rb[1:1]` or `rspec spec/unit/baseball_spec.rb[1:1:1]` depending on how nested the test case is.

Comment: Note that if your shell is ZSH (as is now default with all Macs), you need to wrap the last argument in quotes to prevent the `zsh: no matches found` error. E.g. `rspec "spec/unit/baseball_spec.rb[1:1]"`

Answer (score 9):

For single example of spec file  you need to add line number at the last , For Example

```
rspec spec/controllers/api/v1/card_list_controller_spec.rb:35
```

For single file you can specify your file path, For Example

```
rspec spec/controllers/api/v1/card_list_controller_spec.rb
```

For Whole Rspec Example in spec folder, you can try with this command

```
bundle exec rspec spec
```

Answer (score 7):

For model, it will run case on line number 5 only

```
bundle exec rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb:5
```

For controller : it will run case on line number 5 only

```
bundle exec rspec spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:5
```

For signal model or controller remove line number from above

To run case on all models

```
bundle exec rspec spec/models
```

To run case on all controller

```
bundle exec rspec spec/controllers
```

To run all cases

```
 bundle exec rspec
```

Answer (score 5):

#### In rails 5,

I used this way to run single test file(all the tests in one file)

```
rails test -n /TopicsControllerTest/ -v
```

Class name can be used to match to the desired file `TopicsControllerTest`

My class `class TopicsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest`

Output :

[image]

If You want you can tweak the regex to match to single test method  `\TopicsControllerTest#test_Should_delete\`

```
rails test -n /TopicsControllerTest#test_Should_delete/ -v
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
 rspec spec/controllers/groups_controller_spec.rb:<line_number>
```

line number should be line number of 'describe' or 'it' lines so that it will run tests present in that particular block.
instead it will execute all the lines next to line_number.

also you can create block with custom name and then can execute those blocks only.

Answer (score 1):

starting with rspec 2 you can use the following:

```
# in spec/spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.filter_run :focus => true
  config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true
end

# in spec/any_spec.rb
describe "something" do
  it "does something", :focus => true do
    # ....
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Given you're on a rails 3 project with rspec 2, From the rails root directory:

```
  bundle exec rspec spec/controllers/groups_controller_spec.rb
```

should definitely work.  i got tired of typing that so i created an alias to shorten 'bundle exec rspec' to 'bersp'

'bundle exec' is so that it loads the exact gem environment specified in your gem file: http://gembundler.com/

Rspec2 switched from the 'spec' command to the 'rspec' command.

Answer (score 0):

I use this guard gem to auto-run my test. It execute test after create or update operations on test file.

https://github.com/guard/guard-test

or 
 usually you can run using following command

rspec spec/controllers/groups_controller_spec.rb

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
 rspec/spec/features/controller/spec_file_name.rb
 rspec/spec/features/controller_name.rb         #run all the specs in this controller
```