# What are the differences between the commands: spec, rspec, rake spec?

Tags: testing, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3

Here is a thread I looked at:

[How to run a single RSpec test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116668/rspec-how-to-run-a-single-test)

One answer says to use `rspec` to run tests. Another answer (originally?) said to use `rake spec` to run tests but then a commenter said it's `spec` not `rake spec`.  And I have some notes on using rspec that say:

```
#RSpec prefix not required if you run your program
#with `spec` command 

RSpec.describe 'some task' do
  it 'blah blah blah' do
    true
  end
end
```

I can find no information on the `spec` command, and it doesn't appear to exist on my system:

```
$ which rspec
/Users/7stud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rspec

$ which spec
$
```

Is the `spec` command a rails feature?

Comment: The `spec` command was used for RSpec 1; from RSpec 2, it switched to the `rspec` command.  As for the difference between running `$ rake spec` and `$ rspec`, the best explanation I can find is [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/208#issuecomment-413114).

Comment: Ah.  Thanks @PaulFioravanti.