# How to 'rake spec' one directory, e.g. models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rake

I can `rake spec` and all specs run.

However trying to run specs for one directory, as in

```
rake spec/models/ or rake spec/models/*.rb
```

does not provide any output or errors.

One option is that I can do

```
rspec spec/models/*.rb
```

or

```
rspec spec/models/
```

but I was wondering if I could stay within Rake.

Comment: May be you can read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143925/how-do-you-run-a-single-test-spec-file-in-rspec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `rake spec:models` instead of `rake spec/models`. Run `rake -T | grep spec` to see all the available rake spec tasks.

UPDATE: Running your specs through `rake spec` may be slower than running them through `rspec spec`, said by the rspec-rails guys. Read de installation section of [rspec-rails](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails).

Answer (score 1):

Use `SPEC` env. variable:

`rake spec SPEC=spec/models`